# Was the United Kingdom the only faction in the Second World War that used Operations Research?

Tags: mathematics, world-war-2

I'm aware of work done by the Army Operational Research Group from the United Kingdom's Ministry of Supply. I know Stigler's Diet Problem came out in 1939, if I'm recalling that correctly. However, I wasn't able to find out if it had been in use during the war. I know there were some statistics groups in American universities, which supported the war effort, but I have not been able to determine, if they did any operations research.

I apologize if this belongs on the History site versus this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operations Research is a somewhat eclectic term. The British coined and promoted it, so in the early stages they were the only ones using it even if others were doing similar things under different names, before and after. On the US military uses there is a comprehensive monograph, [History of Operations Research in the United States Army by Schrader](https://history.army.mil/html/books/hist_op_research/CMH_70-102-1.pdf) (freely available), in three volumes. Schrader uses a substantive description rather than the name to trace pre-history of Operations Research all the way back to the Napoleon wars. Here are some excerpts:

> "*The starting date for this study, 1942, was determined by the first efforts to create an OR capability in the  U.S.  Army;  the  ending  date,  1962,  was  determined  by  the  beginning  of  the  major  changes  in  Army  organization  and  procedures  instituted  by  Secretary  of  Defense  Robert  S. McNamara, notably the initiation of efforts to reorganize the  Army  along  functional  lines  and  to  consolidate  related  activities  under  major  functional  commands,  such  as  the  U.S. Army Combat Developments Command and the U.S. 
>   Army Materiel Command... Between 1942 and 1962, the main thrust of OR work in the U.S. Army was in fact the improvement of weapons and equipment, organiza-
>   tion, tactical doctrine, and, to a lesser degree, the formulation of higher-level strategy and policy pertaining to the political, economic, and social issues facing the Army.*"
>
> [...] *The  United  States  Navy  owns  the  distinction  of  having  the  fi  rst  active  OR  group  in  the  U.S.  armed  forces:  the  Mine  Warfare  Operations  Research  Group  (MWORG),  established informally in January 1942.
>   The Navy’s   early   adoption of OR was partly the result of prewar contacts with British OR groups at RAF Coastal Command and the Admiralty working on problems of naval mining, antisubmarine warfare,  and  convoy  organization.  The  work  being  done  in  Britain was directly applicable to the problems faced by the U.S. Navy immediately after the Pearl Harbor attack... MWORG was officially established as part of the U.S. Navy  Bureau  of  Ordnance’s  Re
>   search  Division  on  24  June  1942,  but  it  had  existed  informally  since  late  January  1942  and  thus  merits  distinction  as  the  first  OR  organization  in  the  U.S.  armed  forces.*
>
> *MWORG  grew  out  of  work  being  done on countermeasures for German magnetic mines from December 1939 at the Naval Ordnance Laboratory (NOL) in Washington, D.C. The NOL Mine Research Unit, led from early 1940 by Ellis A. Johnson, a Carnegie Institution physicist,  focused  on  techniques  for  sweeping  for  magnetic  mines and degaussing (demagnetizing) U.S. naval and merchant vessels. In July 1940, Ralph D. Bennett, a professor of electrical engineering at MIT, was called to active duty as a  lieutenant  commander,  U.S.  Naval  Reserve  (USNR)  and  was assigned the task of expanding NOL staff, which he did by  bringing  in  accomplished  scientists  of  his  acquaintance, increasing the scientific staff at NOL from a dozen to nearly  one  thousand.*"

Starting in 1942 Army air, ground and service forces joined the Navy.

Comment: Your last sentence there, taken out of context, might cause some consternation in the Pentagon :-)

Answer (score 6):

In World War II, Andrey Kolmogorov did what you might call operations research, in Russia, for air defense  problems.  His [wikipedia bio article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov#Adulthood) says

> During World War II Kolmogorov contributed to the Russian war effort by applying statistical theory to artillery fire, developing a scheme of stochastic distribution of barrage balloons intended to help protect Moscow from German bombers.[22]

The cited reference is to a modern secondary pop-history work, not to an authoritative primary account, but you might be able to trace back from there.  This 1942 or 1943 [report by Norbert Wiener](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a800403.pdf) references this or similar work at p.11 of the pdf file.  Rodrigo  de Azevedo comments that K's air defense work is also discussed in a  History 
 SE [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/39634/17887), with further references.

Comment: Related: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/39634/17887